# Show that there exists $x_{n} \in A$ such that $x_{n} > \sup A -\dfrac{1}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that there exists $x_{n} \in A$ such that $x_{n} > \sup A -\dfrac{1}{n}$

I am not sure on how to prove this. Would it be by contradiction?

Comment: How about $x_n=5-2/n$

Comment: what is $A$? Which set?

Comment: It should be a set of real numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $h$ be a given positive number.

If we had $x\le \sup A-h \:\:\: \forall x\in A$, then $\sup A -h$ would be an upper bound for $A$ smaller than its least upper bound. Therefore we must have $x> \sup A-h$ for at least one $x\in A$. In your case take $\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A]{h=\frac{1}{n}}$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $s=\sup A$ is the smallest upper bound of $A$. I assume that $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$, bounded from above, so that $s$ exists.

Therefore, for every $\epsilon > 0$, $s-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound of $A$. Then you can find $x_{\epsilon} \in A$ that satisfies $x_{\epsilon} > s- \epsilon$. Apply this to $\epsilon = 1/n$.

Answer (score 0):

If there do not exist such a $x_n$, then all elements in A are less or equal to $sup(A) - \frac{1}{n}$, then $sup(A) \leq sup(A) - \frac{1}{n}$