# Show that there is a sequence such that the limit is Sup A

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be non-empty and bounded above.
Show that there is a sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in A such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=\sup A$

I understand the proof will end on showing we have satisfied the limit definition,
$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists n\in \mathbb{N} \forall n>N$ : $\left|x_{n}-\alpha\right| < \varepsilon$
however I am unsure of how to start.

Comment: Use Archemedian principle and find a sequence.

Comment: Hint : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605420/show-that-there-exists-x-n-in-a-such-that-x-n-sup-a-dfrac1n

Comment: This is more or less the same as [your last question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605420/show-that-there-exists-x-n-in-a-such-that-x-n-sup-a-dfrac1n).